# Is it possible to assign a static external IP to App Engine Flex?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google has documentation for [setting up an external IP for App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip). However, I have a requirement to set up an external IP for App Engine Flex.

I have followed the tutorial and successfully created a subnetwork with a Cloud Router and Cloud NAT that is connected to an external static IP. I tested that the setup works by creating a VM instance in it, and seeing that all egress traffic does indeed originate from the reserved external static IP.

However, when I deploy the App Engine Flex app to this subnetwork, its requests are not routed through the reserved static IP, but appear to be using the shared IP address pool provided by Google. Everything works normally, and there are no deploy errors, just the reserved external IP is not used. The app is assigned to the subnetwork in app.yaml:

```
network:
  name: default
  subnetwork_name: app-engine-subnet
```

Any hints on getting this Flex instance to route its egress traffic through the reserved external IP? I am aware that this can be done using a VM instance as a proxy, but I'd prefer using Cloud NAT instead.

Comment: As a side note to the accepted answer, Google App Engine Flex dynamically generates VM instances with temporary IP addresses to manage load and scale the service, therefore there is not a provided way to access App Engine instances using a private static IP address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Google Cloud NAT documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/troubleshooting#using-nat), Cloud NAT cannot be used with VMs that have an external IP address.  App Engine Flex does not support VMs with internal IPs only ([Google App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooter/connectivity-questions#does_not_support_virtual_machines_with_internal_ip_addresses_only)), so NAT will not work.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone seeing this in 2023, there is a way to use a Static IP using Cloud NAT. In OP's case (subnetwork, Cloud Route, Cloud NAT and reserved external IP in place), the `instance_ip_mode` setting would have been added to the `network:` block with `internal` as its value, like so:

```
network:
  name: default
  subnetwork_name: app-engine-subnet
  instance_ip_mode: internal
```

(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=node.js#network_settings)

Also note that "Private Google Access" has to be enabled on the subnetwork, even though it's technically not a requirement since a Cloud NAT is configured, App Engine will not deploy if it is disabled.

Egress traffic for the service will now route through Cloud NAT, using the reserved static IP.

Comment: The app engine 'standard' (not flexible) guide tells to add this in the `app.yaml` in order to specify a connector.

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
  egress_setting: all-traffic
```

Judging by your answer, it seems we no longer need a connector for this to work? Just a subnet is enough? See [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip)

Comment: Can confirm, that you don't need a connector for this purpose