# Setting static outbound IP address for App Engine(Flex)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I want to set a static outbound IP address for my App Engine instance, hence I went through [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-ip-addresses) documentation. I followed all the steps but I am not able to see any traffic logged in the Cloud NAT for the IP address I specified in step 5 (Reserve a static IP address). I realized that this documentation is applicable for App Engine Standard environment and I deploy the instances of my application in App Engine Flex Environment. Does this documentation apply to App Engine Flex Environment as well? If not, how should I setup outbound static IP address for my App Engine flex instances?

Comment: Did you try the method in the documentation? What was the result? Did you compare costs between App Engine Flexible + that method versus using Compute Engine? App Engine is not designed for your use case. While it is possible (VPC Connector + Cloud NAT), the pain of configuration plus costs indicates Compute Engine is often the better solution. You can also tunnel your traffic through a small GCE instance - I use SSH tunneling to GCE when I need to speak to an IP restricted API. However, the more services you deploy the more fragile the solution becomes.

Comment: How should I tunnel my app engine traffic through the GCE instance? I am deploying a Java application using a docker.

Comment: 1) Create an SSH tunnel on GCE: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling 2) Configure your Java App to call the tunnel endpoint which will forward the traffic to the API. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example#local-forwarding

Comment: Test the SSH tunnel (running on GCE) by using curl from your desktop. Configure SSH to forward traffic to an endpoint that returns your public IP address such as https://ipinfo.io/ip. Once you have the tunnel configured correctly then update your Java App.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to assign a static external IP to App Engine Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013607/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-static-external-ip-to-app-engine-flex)