# How can I add Static IP to Google App Engine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, static-ip-address

I'm trying to add static IP to the app engine( For spring-boot service ). I have done all other configurations, But when I add this line

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
  egress_setting: all-traffic
```

to app.yaml and deploy It'giving me bellow error

```
GCLOUD: Unexpected attribute 'egress_setting' for object of type VpcAccessConnector.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you need to reserve a static ip for? if it's for your GAE app's inbound domain then as far as I know, that's not possible at the moment.

Comment: @AtefH. I'm need to send a file using GAE app engine.  So I need to white list the service IP from other end

Comment: @Sahan.java can you show your complete app.yaml (redacting any confidential data)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to assign a static external IP to App Engine Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013607/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-static-external-ip-to-app-engine-flex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a gcloud parsing error. Update gcloud CLI to the latest version and try again!